Proof that the extremum of a function is a critical point
I'm following a proof given by Spivak in his textbook "Calculus" and one of the steps seems slightly unjustified to me. Firstly, here's the theorem:

If $f$ is a function defined on $(a,b)$ and it has a maximum at $x\in(a,b)$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f'(x) = 0$

Now, the proof is as follows. Let $0 < h < b - x$. Then, $f(x+h) < f(b)$. Thus, $f(x+h) \leq f(x)$ since $x$ is the maximal point. Thus, $f(x+h) - f(x)\leq 0$. Now, since $h$ is positive:
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq 0$$
Intuitively, it makes sense to conclude the following:
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\leq 0$$
However, how would we show this using the epsilon-delta definition of the one-sided limit? In other words, since $L$ is the value of the limit as shown below, how do we prove that $L\leq 0$? I suppose that's how you can formally show that the above statement is true.
$$0 < h < b - x\implies \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - L\right| < \epsilon$$

Does this answer your question? If $f(x) >0$ for all $x$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \ge 0$ (Mutatis mutandis of course, i.e. apply it to $g(h):=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ instead of $f(x)$, $\lim_{h\to0^+}$ instead of $x\to a$, and assume only $g\ge0$, not $g>0$): If $g(h)\ge0$ for all $h\in(0,b-x)$, then $\lim_{0^+}g\ge0$, which is exactly what you wanted.
